# String column Search/Replace GUIDs

Tags: sql-server, search, replace, sql-server-2000, profiling

i have a SQL Profiler trace saved to a table in SQL Server.

i want to perform sum/avg/count analysis of CPU/Reads/Duration on the queries in the trace. But most of the profiler data records calls to stored procedures with `uniqueidentifer` parameter(s):

```
EXECUTE GetTransactionCounts @BankGUID = '{231281D7-F6C2-4EAE-98AE-E9196D8016F0}', @SessionGUID='{7F34361F-CEEA-4CEA-8CBD-2704FFE92DEF}'
SELECT SUM(Total) AS Total FROM fn_BalancingAdditionsUS('{C08961DB-0B6A-4E67-A82B-5BBBA0A84A74}')
EXEC CreateCloser '{7F34361F-CEEA-4CEA-8CBD-2704FFE92DEF}', NULL , '{08E74DBB-3BC4-49A7-AA10-95AA6BD24784}'
EXECUTE GetMachineImpressmentForSession @SessionGUID = '{446881BA-1439-4AD8-B33B-C784120EFBA2}'
SELECT SUM(Total) AS Total FROM fn_BalancingAdditionsCanadian('{446881BA-1439-4AD8-B33B-C784120EFBA2}')
SELECT SUM(Total) AS Total FROM fn_BalancingSubtractionsUS('{446881BA-1439-4AD8-B33B-C784120EFBA2}')
```

So when i try to aggregate the profiler trace data to find the worst performing queries:

```
SELECT
   Description, 
   COUNT(*) AS EventCount,
   AVG(CPU) AS CPU, SUM(CPU) AS CpuTotal,
   AVG(Reads) AS Reads, SUM(Reads) AS ReadsTotal,
   AVG(Duration) AS Duration, SUM(Duration) AS DurationTotal
FROM SlowQueriesTrace
GROUP BY Description
```

then no aggregation occurs, because every GUID is unique. What i need is some way to replace the uniqueidentifier parameters with a generic `%g` marker:

```
EXECUTE GetTransactionCounts @BankGUID = %g, @SessionGUID=%g
SELECT SUM(Total) AS Total FROM fn_BalancingAdditionsUS(%g)
EXEC CreateCloser %g, NULL , %g
EXECUTE GetMachineImpressmentForSession @SessionGUID = %g
SELECT SUM(Total) AS Total FROM fn_BalancingAdditionsCanadian(%g)
SELECT SUM(Total) AS Total FROM fn_BalancingSubtractionsUS(%g)
```

Then my aggregation will work.

Aside from exporting the table to Excel and hand editing all 10,270 events, can anything think of any way to perform GUID search & replace pattern matching inside SQL Server?

---

**Other hacks i tried**:

Trim `description` to first 40 characters (i.e. `CAST(description AS varchar(40))`):

```
EXECUTE GetTransactionCounts @BankGUID =
SELECT SUM(Total) AS Total FROM fn_Balan
EXEC CreateCloser '{7F34361F-CEEA-4CEA-8
EXECUTE GetMachineImpressmentForSession 
SELECT SUM(Total) AS Total FROM fn_Balan
SELECT SUM(Total) AS Total FROM fn_Balan
```

Except that merges items that shouldn't be merged, and other items that should be merged are not.

Use SoundEx:

```
E223
S423
E220
E223
S423
```

Except that you can see lines that are completely different are given the same soundex. Also i am unable to determine what query `S338` corresponds to.

---

The hack i ended up using was to create a new `Category` column, initally null. i then spent two hours with carefully selected `LIKE` clauses to pick out a particular query and then "tag" them all with the query. e.g.:

```
UPDATE QueryTrace
SET Category = 'EXECUTE GetTransactionCounts @BankGUID ='
WHERE Description LIKE 'EXECUTE GetTransactionCounts @BankGUID =%'
```

and

```
UPDATE QueryTrace
SET Category = 'SELECT SUM(Total) AS Total FROM fn_BalancingAdditionsCanadian'
WHERE Description LIKE '%FROM fn_BalancingAdditionsCanadian%'
```

That doesn't mean i don't need a solution using this question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [ClearTrace](http://www.scalesql.com/cleartrace/) which performs certain query parameterisations/normalisations?

Another option is to use a CLR function: [Determining Poorly Performing Queries for Tuning from SQL Server Workload Trace Files](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com/2008/08/determining-poorly-performing-queries.html)

> Whenever you gather workload traces to
>   identify poorly performing queries,
>   you need to import this data into a
>   database table, and to "normalise" and
>   aggregate this information to identify
>   the worst offenders. This can be done
>   in a variety of ways. One way is to
>   define a regular expression such as
>   this SQL CLR method based on work done
>   by Itzik Ben-Gan and modified by Adam
>   Machanic:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true)]
public static SqlString sqlsig(SqlString querystring)
{
    return (SqlString)Regex.Replace(
       querystring.Value,
       @"([\s,(=<>!](?![^\]]+[\]]))(?:(?:(?:(?:(?# expression coming
       )(?:([N])?(')(?:[^']'')*('))(?# character
       )(?:0x[\da-fA-F]*)(?# binary
       )(?:[-+]?(?:(?:[\d]*\.[\d]*[\d]+)(?# precise number
       )(?:[eE]?[\d]*)))(?# imprecise number
       )(?:[~]?[-+]?(?:[\d]+))(?# integer
       )(?:[nN][uU][lL][lL])(?# null
       ))(?:[\s]?[\+\-\*\/\%\&\\^][\s]?)?)+(?# operators
       )))",
       @"$1$2$3#$4");
}
```

---

**Edit by OP**: i had not heard of ClearTrace. i tried it:

[image]

**Edit**: Did you use the right trace template to gather the trace?

Comment: +1 ClearTrace is *exactly* the way to go here. It's easy to use and is built specifically to solve the problem you're dealing with.

Comment: Hopefully not the only way to go.

Comment: I've used ClearTrace many times and not encountered that error